# Microsoft Word: Camel Case Typing

Tags: ms-word, camelcasing

Does anyone know if there is a shortcut, feature or plugin available for Microsoft Word that can make highlighted text or styles in *method camel case*, so variableName not just ClassName.

I know there is the Capitalise Each Word shortcut but this also capitalises the first word.

I know its not really *Programmy* but its worth a shot, cheers!

Comment: And, for the reason you gave, this question will soon be closed. General purpose software questions are not allowed on SO and should be asked on SuperUser

Answer (score 1):

Like so many things MicroSoft, they develope an application until it is works for 80% the cases it should support and call it done.

None of their office word application have any concept of a "Camel Case" word such as "camelCaseWord".

In my case, I would like a spell check to make each word in a camel case word to spell check independently.

In your case, I would suggest you create your own macro that would capitalize the first letter of each word in the selected text then remove the spaces between words.  In fact someone already wrote one: 
[Convert Highlighted Text revised](https://www.macros.com/usermacs/umconverthighlightedtextrevised.htm)